# A question on the right translation

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Here is a claim:

> Let $G$ be a right topological group and $g$ be any element of $G$. Then the right translation  $R_g$ of $G$ by $g$ is a homeomorphism of the space $G$ onto itself.

How can I reach this conclusion?

Comment: I strongly assume that the continuity of $R_g$ and $R_{g^{-1}}$ follows very immediately from your definition of right topological group. (And it should read homEomorphism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of a right topological group the right translation $R_g$ is assumed to be continuous.

Moreover the inverse of $R_g$ is just $R_{g^{-1}}$, which is another right translation and hence also continuous.

Therefore $R_g$ is an homeomorphism.

Comment: Note that the OP consider a *right* topological group, that is a group with a topology such that the translation on the right are continuous. However your argument is still valid.

Comment: Okay. I see. I didn't see that the inverse of $R_g$ is $R_{g^{-1}}$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ...and, of course, right/left translation in a group is *always* a bijection...